# ERROR TypeError: a.getCountryCodeOrDefault is not a function

Tags: angular, validation, phone-number, libphonenumber, ngx-international-phone-number

I'm trying to use `google-libphonenumber` package in an Angular project for validating phone number

```js
import { PhoneNumberUtil } from 'google-libphonenumber';

  public phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

  phoneUtil.isValidNumber('+919421013328');
```

but it gives me

> TypeError: a.getCountryCodeOrDefault is not a function.

can someone please help me with this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the google-libphonenumber package readme](https://github.com/ruimarinho/google-libphonenumber#usage):

> Most `libphonenumber` functions expect to receive an instance of `libphonenumber.PhoneNumber` which can be obtained by calling `phoneUtil.parse` or phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput on a raw (string) number, otherwise it will throw errors like TypeError: `a.getCountryCodeOrDefault` is not a function.

```js
phoneUtil.isValidNumberForRegion(phoneUtil.parse('202-456-1414', 'US'), 'US');
```

or if you have multiple country codes:

```js
phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput('+919421013329');
```

Comment: I have numbers with multiple country codes so I used `phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput`. Thank you :)